# PHP Помогите прочитать все строки файла без первой

Tags: php

Я начал делать так - Первая - массив строк файла file.txt без первой строки, Вторая - текст файла file.txt без первой строки. Но пока ничего не работает. Помогите исправить код

```
$row_array = array_slice(file('file.txt'), 1)) 

$text = implode('', array_slice(file('file.txt'), 1)))
```

Comment: Что именно не работает? Какие входные данные, какие выходные?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$lines = file('file.txt');
array_shift($lines);
```

[array_shift](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-shift.php) - Извлекает первый элемент массива, в итоге в `$lines` будут строки файла без первой строки

Текст будет таким: `$text = implode(PHP_EOL, $lines);`

Но если итог надо записать в файл, то `implode` не обязателен:

```
file_put_contents('filename.txt', $lines);
```

При одномерном массиве в качестве параметра будет эквивалентно вызову
   `file_put_contents($filename, implode('', $array)).`